# Strip Static MFC Dependency from .lib File

Tags: c++, mfc, static

I have pre-compiled .lib files and link them to a c++ project in a solution. When I build the solution, I receive a lot of error messages like: "terminate is already defined in msvcrtd.dll". I have Googled that this is because .lib files already contain static MS VC dependencies and my project is using them as a shared lib.
I have no sources for these .lib files and I can't change the projects' MS VC dependencies settings.
What will you suggest? Is there a tool which strips all dependencies from .lib files or do something else to solve my problem?

Comment: No.  If you cannot change the /MD option to /MT then you are stuck, you cannot use this library.  Contact the library owner for support.